# Windows move between monitors at 10:00 AM every day

Tags: windows-7

- Windows 7
- Four monitors
- System video Intel HD Graphics 4600
- Video card NVIDIA GeForce GT 610
- All up to date drivers

How do I find what is happening at 10:00 AM?
How do I keep the windows from moving?

Comment: Do they always move in the same way, to the same monitor(s)? Have you checked the Task Scheduler to see what is scheduled to run at 10am? What programs are running on your computer at that time of day? We need more information before we'll be able to get you an answer. Please use the EDIT button to add the answers to these questions as well as any other relevant data you are aware of to your question.

Comment: Sounds like Windows update is installing a driver update that temporarily disables the second display.

Comment: Don't remember the solution but thanks for the comments. I no longer work there.